# Trying to save long long into NSNumber from String

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I am trying to save a long long number (received as a string) such as '80182916772147201' into an NSNumber.

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterBehaviorDefault];

[item setObject:[f numberFromString:@"80182916772147201"] forKey:@"theID"];
[f release];
```

When I NSLog this out, assuming the string was '80182916772147201' I get:

```
NSLog(@"%lld", [[item objectForKey:@"theID"] longLongValue]);
```

Returns: '80182916772147200' - Note the rounded down final digit.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `NSNumberFormatter` has decided to represent that number as a floating-point number. To force it to use integers only:

```
[f setAllowsFloats:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this?

```
NSString *numStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu", [myNum unsignedLongLongValue]];
```

This makes a few reasonable assumptions such as numStr will only contain numeric digits and it contains a 'valid' unsigned long long value. A drawback to this approach is that UTF8String creates what essentially amounts to [[numStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] bytes], or in other words something along the lines of 32 bytes of autoreleased memory per call. For the vast majority of uses, this is no problem what-so-ever.

For an example of how to add something like unsignedLongLongValue to NSString that is both very fast and uses no autoreleased memory as a side effect, take a look at the end of my (long) answer to this SO question. Specifically the example implementation of rklIntValue, which would require only trivial modifications to implement unsignedLongLongValue.